# How to execute a Matlab function in MS Visual C++?

Tags: c++, windows, matlab, visual-c++, mixed-programming

I have 2 separate functions which one is in MS visual C++ and another is in Matlab. How do I execute the Matlab file in MS VISUAL? Is there a windows function to load the `.m` file and execute it straightly?

Comment: You would typically use the matlab compiler to make a DLL that can be consumed by your program.

Comment: i see! Is the process very tedious?

Comment: last question. If i have the matlab compiler to make it into DLL, do i still need the Matlab installed on a computer for the VC++ to run the DLL?

Comment: You need the target machine to have the MATLAB compiler runtime. It's documented clearly in the MATLAB docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Two ways to run Matlab code in C++:

1. #### Call MATLAB Engine directly.

   The target machine needs to have the MATLAB installed. Check out [Call MATLAB Functions from C and C++ Applications](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/calling-matlab-software-from-a-c-application.html) for more info and examples.
2. #### Distribute MATLAB code into independent shared library (dlls).

   The target machine needs to have the MATLAB compiler runtime. Check out [here](http://blog-ythu.github.io/2012/04/29/mixed-programming-distribute-MATLAB/) on how to do this (with detail steps and example).