# How to execute a Matlab script from C++

Tags: c++, matlab

I have a C++ program in Visual Studio that records data and saves it into a file. I want to do some Matlab analysis reading from that file and save the results in a separate one. Then, my C++ program keeps going.

Is there any way to do this automatically coding the call in C++ when Matlab is open in the same computer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There seems to be a couple of useful links [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cdce8399-95f9-4a67-a2dd-0b57bf9bf24c/calling-matlab-from-c?forum=vclanguage)

Comment: There appear to be some duplicates, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23061113/how-to-execute-a-matlab-function-in-ms-visual-c), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429243/how-to-call-matlab-functions-from-c) [and](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774830/call-matlab-in-c-code-using-methods-in-engine-h) [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576876/matlab-in-c-c-and-c-c-in-matlab) [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757613/calling-matlab-from-c) [more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654965/how-do-i-use-matlab-engine-in-my-code-for-calling-engopensingleuse)

Comment: Thanks! I read through them, and it is a possible solution that I had found, but that is to translate a Matlab code to C++. However, I am using a whole Matlab Toolbox, that is why my need is to call Matlab from VS and execute the script in Matlab rather thatn translate the toolbox, which I can't do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways to call MATLAB from C++ depending on your needs. Many similar questions have been asked here in the past and I will refer to those and as well give you a solution as your requirement seems to be different.

1. **Do you want MATLAB C or C++ API?** Then use `mex` functions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576876/matlab-in-c-c-and-c-c-in-matlab), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429243/how-to-call-matlab-functions-from-c), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757613/calling-matlab-from-c) and the actual [MATLAB documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-mex-files.html)
2. **Do you want to convert your MATLAB program to C++?** Then use [MATLAB Coder](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/) described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126407/matlab-compiler-vs-matlab-coder), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940669/matlab-coder-vs-hand-coding) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720498/matlab-coder-matlab-to-c)
3. **Do you want to run a MATLAB script from within C++?** Then call [MATLAB Engine](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html) or write a shell script and have that called from C++ described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001183/how-to-call-matlab-functions-from-the-linux-command-line) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646217/how-to-run-a-bash-script-from-c-program)

Your problem falls under the third category. So you need to either call MATLAB engine (**See Tal Darom's answer**)  or write a shell script. I will explain the latter. Lets write a shell script called `matlab_script.sh`:

```
#/bin/sh
matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash < your_matlab_file.m
```

then in your C++ code do this:

```
system("matlab_script.sh");
```

You need `matlab_script.sh` to be executable. Under linux you normally do `chmod +x matlab_script.sh`

Comment: You don't need to go over a shell script, and a user of a program using the Matlab Engine does not need to have Matlab installed to run it, by using the Matlab Compiler.

Comment: Isn't Matlab compiler SDK too much of an overkill for OP's needs? He is using Matlab toolboxes where he probably wants to interactively, edit both his Matlab scripts and his C++ code. His Matlab and C++ programs actually never to talk to each other. C++ writes and Matlab reads, basic IO. And a shell script  will do exactly that.

Comment: It is not an answer to current OP's question, but important note: MATLAB Engine needs to have MATLAB installed at the same PC, while using .exe and .dll and etc sometimes needs just MATLAB Runtime.

Comment: Does the batch script solution running matlab on the command line also work on a Windows machine?

Comment: Update: Here's a working solution on Windows 10: >matlab -nodesktop -nosplash " your_matlab_file; exit;"

Answer (score 1):

You can start a matlab engine from within a program, and run matlab scripts using matlab engine API.

see documentation at: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html

Comment: This is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [the Matlab Compiler SDK](http://mathworks.com/products/matlab-compiler-sdk/), which turns your matlab code into a standalone program or library.

You can then call this libary from your C++ code, and the end user won't even need to have Matlab installed (just the Compiler Runtime, which you can deploy "royalty-free"), see [this web page](http://mathworks.com/products/matlab-compiler-sdk/features.html#key-features) for what you can do with it.