# how call a written machine learning algorithm in matlab, in a c++ program?

Tags: c++, matlab

I have written a machine learning algorithm (MLP) for prediction in matlab, I want to call it, in a specific times, in a simulation (OMNET++) that is based on c++. how can I call this ML algorithm in this c++ program? my implementations is in linux.
many thanks.

Comment: Read this: [MATLAB C++ Libraries](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-cpp-library-functions.html) and  [Call MATLAB Functions from C++](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-c-1.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to execute any file from within a C++ code.

```
system(<matlab_file_name>)
```

**Usage example:** Launch an instance of notepad from a c++ file:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Launching notepad..." <<endl;
    system("notepad.exe");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks. does it work in linux too? my implementation is in linux.

Comment: Yes, it should work in Linux too.

Comment: MATLAB script is not an executable file unless published, which requires additional licenced toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

I run this code and it works.

```
const char* cmd1="gnome-terminal -x sh -c \'/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r \"run(\'/home/veins/MLP/estimate.m\');exit;\'";
int s=system(cmd1);
```

Comment: this also works.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115766/how-to-execute-a-matlab-script-from-c